# How to vary classes depending on content type?

Tags: 8, theming

In my `page.html.twig` template file, I'm looking to set classes depending on the content type the page is being viewed. I pretty much have two options, if the page being viewed is a program page, then I want one style applied to the div, if it's anything else, then the other style can be applied.

```
{% 
  set aside_classes = [
    node.content-type is 'program' ? 'program',
    node.content-type is anything else ? 'standard'
  ]
%}
```

I know the above code is not proper but it's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I would then have the following code below on my div:

```
<div{{ content_attributes.addClass(aside_classes) }}>
```

Am I going about this right or is there a better way to achieve this?

EDIT:
Here are my kint variables. Not sure if this helps at all?:
[image: Kint Variables]

Comment: With default Drupal config, you should see two classes automatically created on the body tag for all page types in Drupal. I would expect you to see the classes ".path-node" and ".node-type-program". This is done in the html.twig template file with {{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }} on the body tag. Do these not work for your situation?

Comment: I see what you're saying but I'd prefer to add the style to the specific div within the body depending on the content type. 
Would the following work?
node_type is 'program' ? 'program'.
But how would I tell it to add 'standard' if it's anything else?

Comment: @ACanadianCoder something like this should work {% node.content-type is 'program' ? 'program' : 'standard' %}

Comment: @cchen that didn't seem to work. Just got a page error.

Comment: @ACanadianCoder sorry that was not the exact working code..I think the answer below should work, you just need to modify it a little bit to make for the page level template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about page.html.twig. Would have to dig around...

In node.html.twig:

```
{%
  set newClassNameVar = [
    node.type.entity.label == 'Program' ? 'Program' : 'Not Program'
  ]
%}

<div{{ attributes.addClass(newClassNameVar) }}></div>
```

or:

```
{%
  set newClassNameVar = [
    node.bundle == 'content__type' ? 'set-yes-class' : 'set-no-class'
  ]
%}

<div{{ attributes.addClass(newClassNameVar) }}></div>
```

use debug such as `{{ dump(_context | keys) }}` to see what is available and best suits your use case.

Comment: I've added my kint screengrab to the original post from my page.html.twig file. Does any of that help?

Comment: I ended up just using your method mentioned above but used {% if node.bundle == 'program' %} and that seemed to work. I still think there's a more elegant way of doing it similar to what @cchen had suggested in the above post but this will work for now. Thanks again!

Comment: updated my answer with two options, credit to @cchen too

Comment: Awesome...that works and looks much nicer...however, instead of using the label, is there a way of using the machine name? ex. node.type.entity.machine_name == 'program'. Sorry for being so picky.

Comment: I was looking myself and will try some more when I can. node.type.entity.machine_name looks like the right idea. Also I am always a fan of {{ dump(node | keys) }}, it's a lot lighter than kint. {{ dump(_context | keys) }} is a quick way to see everything available such as 'node', 'elements', 'content'...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to add the class programmatically in your custom theme [as discussed here](https://www.drupal.org/project/uikit/issues/3003985#comment-13449809).

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node_type'])) {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

    // Add node-TYPE class to the element.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'page-node-' . $node->getType();
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'page-node-' . $node->id();
  }
}
```